# How to return exact value of square root in python?

Tags: python

If I input 25, answer should be 5 as integer. If I input 24 answer should be 4.898989486 float. Is this possible to do in python?

Context-: I need to write a code to find next perfect square.

```
import math

def find_next_square(sq):
    # Return the next square if sq is a square, -1 otherwise
    sq2=math.sqrt(sq)
    xyz=isinstance(sq2, int)
    if (xyz==True):
        print("Is perfect square")
        nextsq=sq+1
        print("Next perfect square=",nextsq**2)
    else:
        print("Not perfect square")
        return -1

n=int(input("Enter an integer"))
find_next_square(n)
```

Here is the code.
For 25, this returns, sq2=5.0 hence it returns Not perfect square. I need a way to make this return perfect square.

**Desired behaviour-:**

If I put 25 as n. It should return it as perfect square and return 36.

**Specific problem-:**

Problem here is

```
import math

sq=25
sq2=math.sqrt(sq)
print(sq2)
xyz=isinstance(sq2, int)
print(xyz)
```

Even for sq=25, it will return it as float. That math.sqrt() function. It changes the whole game for me.

**Shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem-:**

```
import math

sq=24
sq2=math.sqrt(sq)
print(sq2)
xyz=isinstance(sq2, int)
print(xyz)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What was the result?

Comment: Why is 5.0 a problem? You could write a function checking `result % 1 == 0` and then convert it to int if true.

Comment: Or `if result.is_integer():` - floats [have that method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer).

Comment: What about `import math` then `math.sqrt(24)`? I get 4.898979485566356, and squaring it again get 23.999999999999996, which is pretty good for floats

Comment: refer this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-decimal-sqrt-method/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import math

ans = math.sqrt(int(input()))  # calculate an answer
print(int(ans) if ans.is_integer() else ans)  # convert answer to int if we can do it
```

Comment: Then, could you accept my answer, please? (If is was helpful)